# Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging fails on Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate

Tags: xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried many different versions of sample / example code, but I cannot get Cloud Messaging to work on iOS (14.5).

The line

`Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;`

Always fails with SharedInstance being null.

To test, I created a new Xamarin Forms project, I added the Nuget package Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging version 4.7.1, and I added the GoogleServices-Info.plist file and set the Build Action to BundleResource.

I added the following code to AppDelegate:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        try
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            // Register your app for remote notifications.
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code fails on the line "Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;".

This issue is also on the GitHub issues section:
https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/486

Comment: did you integrate the google file into the project, and  change the build action to bundle resource? If you still have this problem, maybe your can use different Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging version to try.

Comment: Yes, I added the GoogleServices-Info.plist file and set the Build Action to BundleResource. I also tried versions 3.0.3, 3.1.2, 4.1.1.2, 4.3.0 of the NuGet package.

Comment: I search some info, find [one thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181967/xamarin-firebase-ios-cloudmessaging-messaging-sharedinstance-is-null) that having some problem, you can take a look firstly, then if you still have problems, maybe you can try to use some Firebase Push Notification Plugin to do.

Comment: I'm suffering from this also. Can I ask what is your development environment? I'm on Windows Visual Studio 19 and an iPhone 7 and have read elsewhere that people using Mac don't have this issue. Very frustrating